# compiling error while using sse4.2 function on intel machine

Tags: c++, c, intel, sse, intrinsics

I am trying to use the intrensic function _mm_crc32_u32 on my Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v2 INTEL machine,

I compile the project with the sse4.2 flag enabled (inside the makefile):

```
CCFLAGS += -msse4.2
```

but i still get the error:

> nmmintrin.h:31:3: error: #error "SSE4.2 instruction set not enabled"

any ideas why this might still happen?

Comment: Check the command line being generated by your makefile and ensure that you're seeing the -msse4.2 switch being emitted.

Comment: @PaulR thank you for your answer, the file where the flags are added is passed to the make and i dont see the command line that is generated is simply starts compiling when i call it, is there any way to see the command line that is beeing generated?

Comment: Are you using some sort of IDE ? Note also that CCFLAGS is somewhat non-standard - you may want CFLAGS and/or CXXFLAGS for C and C++ respectively.

Comment: Some indication of what compiler and IDE you're using would be helpful.

Comment: I dont compile inside a IDE, the compile version is: `gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC)`

Comment: So you just type `make` at the command line ? In that case you should be seeing the generated command lines for gcc/g++, no ? (Unless you're doing something funny in the makefile to suppress output ?)

Comment: Post your makefile.  Some standard make templates have a different variable for CFLAGS and CCFLAGS (for C code and C++ code respectively).  We need to verify that your extra parameter is making it onto the GCC command line.